# Function that produces first index of ''3 in a row number occurrence''

Tags: c, function, loops, for-loop, if-statement

i want to create a function that take the inputs of an array and its number of values. The function should look through the array and as soon as it sees a ''3 in a row''(e.g { 1 2 3 4 5 5 5 6 7 8}), in this case 5. The function should print the index of the first 5. Im new to coding so im finding it difficult how to begin. Ive made an attempt but dont know how to proceed.

```
int NewFunction(int array, int numValues){
int i;
int j;
for(i=0;i<numValues;i++){
for(j=i+1;j<numValues;j++){
if(
```

Comment: Please do this yourself on paper for a few different examples. Then describe in prose how you did it. Try to do it in a single description which matches all your attempts. That is going to be your algorithm. The next step is then to find the control structures and when you post your description, someone will help you with the next step.

Comment: If you post code, please make sure that it does compile and can be turned into an executable. For that please copmlete the correct syntax for alll structures you start, include a `main()` definition and all needed includes. You can add more of the final program, e.g. add and output of a suitably typed result variable.

Comment: Please add input data. That does not need to be actual  input reading. For your question, the source of the input is irrelevant, so just adding a statically defined array with hard coded initialisation is good enough. You do know how to read input, don't you? Because that would be a separate (and multiply duplicate) question if you don't. Doing this makes answering easier (which is of course helpful for your own goal) and also demonstrates own effort and your level of knowledge.

Comment: If your description includes "I see the three identical numbers" then take a piece of paper, cut out the size of exactly one number as a "mask". While doing this yourself, move the mask across your list of numbers so that you only ever see a single number. Then try describing how you do it with the obstacle.

Comment: Read the answer below, it does what I proposed as first step. Try to follow it on paper and whether you understand each step as necessary. If not, ask in a comment below that answer, why the step is needed. When you understood each step start programming the description.

Comment: Alternatively, try to find a description of how you do it yourself. There are other ways to do it, possibly less efficient, but that is not imprtant.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I've never coded before so all this info is very helpful for me

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you might want to go with a more descriptive name than `NewFunction`. Also, the array shouldn't be of type `int`, you're probably looking for a pointer to an int.

Furthermore, you don't need a nested loop like that:

```
for(i=0;i<numValues;i++){
for(j=i+1;j<numValues;j++){
```

Imagine doing this by hand, getting a list of about 1000 numbers, trying to find three in a row. How often would you pass through the list? A maximum of once, right? You wouldn't go through the list a thousand times, so neither should your algorithm, therefore you don't need a nested loop here.

What you're looking for is something like this:

```
int threeInARow(int* array, int numValues) {
    int count = 1;  // how many numbers in a row were found
    int current = array[0]; // the number that we're looking for
    int i = 1;
    for (; i < numValues; i++) {
        if (array[i] == current) {
            if (++count == 3) return i - 2;
        }
        else { // a different number is found: start over
            count = 1;
            current = array[i];
        }
    }
    return -1;  // return a value indicating that no result was found
}
```

Comment: What if i wanted to print out the index position of the first occurrence of the ''three in a row''...?

Comment: `int ints[] = { 5, 3 ,4 ,2 ,1 ,4 ,9 ,4, 4, 4, 2 }; printf("index %d\n", threeInARow(ints, sizeof(ints)-sizeof(int)));`

Comment: Ok I get it! Thank you so much! Learnt a whole lot today! :)

Answer (score 0):

Start with a variable: where have you first seen the last value you saw. Let's call it `last`, and initialise it at 0. Then iterate `index` from 1 to the length of the array. If the difference between `index` and `last` is 3, return `last` as the index of the repeating value. If not, check whether `index` is at length. If so, the search failed. Otherwise, if the value at the current index is different from the value at `last`, set `last` to the current index.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ELEMENT 14

int three_in_a_row(int arr[], int n) {

  int i, index, count = 0, max = 0;
  i = -1;

  do {
    i = i + 1;
    if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1]) {
      index = i-1; //because we want the first occurrence
      count++;
      if (count > max) max = count; // 3 elements in a row means that max must be 3-1 
    } else
      count = 0; 
  } while (i < n - 2 && max != 3 - 1);

  return (max == 2 ? index : -1);// -1 indicates no result
}

int main(void) {

  int array[] = {1,10,1,4,4,8,8,8,7,8,8,9,9,2}, index3;
  index3 = three_in_a_row(array, ELEMENT);
  printf("%d\n", index3);

  return (0);
}
```